# Jquery - find value in table

Tags: jquery, find, html-table

How to find value by name? I find name "**Obsah  balení:**" and I need to return a value **3,18 m²** or directly number **3,18**.

Code:

```
<table id="product-detail-info" class="pr-list-parametes">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="pr-detail-parameter-name">
            Frézováná hrana:
         </td>
         <td class="pr-detail-parameter-value">
            ne
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="pr-detail-parameter-name">
            Obsah balení:
         </td>
         <td class="pr-detail-parameter-value">3,18 m²</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="pr-detail-parameter-name">
            Počet desek v balení:
         </td>
         <td class="pr-detail-parameter-value">7 ks</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="pr-detail-parameter-name">
            Počet m² na paletě:
         </td>
         <td class="pr-detail-parameter-value">127,2 m²</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`:cotains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) pseudo-class selector and [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next) method .

```js
console.log(
  // select `td` which cotains the text
  $('td:contains("Obsah balení:")')
  // select the sibling `td` which immediately after the element
  .next()
  // get the text contents
  .text()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="product-detail-info" class="pr-list-parametes">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="pr-detail-parameter-name">
        Frézováná hrana:
      </td>
      <td class="pr-detail-parameter-value">
        ne
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pr-detail-parameter-name">
        Obsah balení:
      </td>
      <td class="pr-detail-parameter-value">3,18 m²</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pr-detail-parameter-name">
        Počet desek v balení:
      </td>
      <td class="pr-detail-parameter-value">7 ks</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pr-detail-parameter-name">
        Počet m² na paletě:
      </td>
      <td class="pr-detail-parameter-value">127,2 m²</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
var getText = $('#product-detail-info tr td').filter(function(){
  return $.trim($(this).text())  == "Obsah balení:";
}).siblings('td').text();

alert(getText);
```